# UWP app with ADAL auth fails when ADFS WIASupportedUserAgents property includes "Mozilla/5.0"

Tags: uwp, adfs, adal

We have a UWP Xamarin Application using ADAL for authentication.

ADFS WIASupportedUserAgents property has been configured to include "Mozilla/5.0"

When the PC is on an external network, authentication works as expected.

When the PC is joined to domain, the browser window never gets to the ADFS login page.

I also have the following capabilities set in the Package.appxmanifest

- privateNetworkClientServer
- internetClientServer
- enterpriseAuthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the app configuration steps described in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store. In particular, please make sure that you configured your redirect URI following the guidance in section "
Find the TodoListClient app's redirect URI".

Comment: Obtaining the redirect URI in addition to ensuring UseCorporateNetwork was checked in the app manifest resolved this issue. Thanks!